# Keyboard Height in Swift 3: Initialiser for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CGFloat'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am trying to get the Keyboard height in swift 3 however I receive the following error,

> Initialiser for conditional binding must have Optional type, not
>   'CGFloat'

for my guard let statement in the following

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ n:Notification) {

 self.keyboardShowing = true

 guard let keyboardHeight = (((n as NSNotification).userInfo! as NSDictionary).object(forKey: UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey) as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size.height else {
   return
 }

}
```

So I am returning the `CGFloat` value of the keyboard height for the `keyboardWillShow` notification. So of course I know it will always return a value when it appears but seems since Swift 3 I have to return an option just in case.

How can I change the `guard let` statement for swift 3 ?

Comment: The linked-to Q&A has answers for Swift 2 and Swift 3.

Comment: You can only use `guard let` and `if let` with optional types. But, because of how you've constructed that expression, it's not an optional.